# unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray' when converting Object to datetime in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, datetime

I keep getting this error whenever I try to convert my columns to the DateTime format. My columns are in the String format, I've tried looking online but I couldn't find anything to help me solve this issue.

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-87-9a285deef407> in <module>
----> 1 pd.to_datetime(bookings_ship_time['purchase_order_requested_cargo_ready_date'], infer_datetime_format=True)
      2 
      3 

c:\users\marcus\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in to_datetime(arg, errors, dayfirst, yearfirst, utc, format, exact, unit, infer_datetime_format, origin, cache)
    799                 result = result.tz_localize(tz)
    800     elif isinstance(arg, ABCSeries):
--> 801         cache_array = _maybe_cache(arg, format, cache, convert_listlike)
    802         if not cache_array.empty:
    803             result = arg.map(cache_array)

c:\users\marcus\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in _maybe_cache(arg, format, cache, convert_listlike)
    171     if cache:
    172         # Perform a quicker unique check
--> 173         if not should_cache(arg):
    174             return cache_array
    175 

c:\users\marcus\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py in should_cache(arg, unique_share, check_count)
    135     assert 0 < unique_share < 1, "unique_share must be in next bounds: (0; 1)"
    136 
--> 137     unique_elements = set(islice(arg, check_count))
    138     if len(unique_elements) > check_count * unique_share:
    139         do_caching = False

TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

The purchase order column information is below:

```
purchase_order_id
1140     [2017-04-10]
1148     [2017-07-01]
1151     [2017-05-30]
3156     [2017-10-13]
3363     [2017-09-08]
             ...     
56584    [2019-09-30]
56585    [2019-09-30]
56586    [2019-09-23]
56587    [2019-09-23]
56588    [2019-09-23]
```

Edit:
Dtype is ('O')
I have tried using the pd.to_datetime method and:

```
bookings_ship_time['purchase_order_requested_cargo_ready_date'] = datetime.strptime(bookings_ship_time['purchase_order_requested_cargo_ready_date'], '%Y/%m/%d')
```

Comment: Add the code you have tried.

Comment: could you provide some more details how `bookings_ship_time['purchase_order_requested_cargo_ready_date']` looks like? dtype etc.

Comment: Just updated the post for both Data type and the code I have tried.

Comment: First remove square bracket and then your solution working perfectly.